# Prepend Duplicate

Tags: jquery, prepend

My code finds the Radio I checked and then finds the next element and prepends that content in the div i want. However when i check a different Radio and then go back  to the previous div it keeps the prepend content and it prepends again. So i end up with duplicates on the div.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="informed"/>
    <span>INFORMED CONSENT</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="release"/>
    <span>RELEASE OF INFORMATION</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="intake"/>
    <span>INTAKE FORM</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="checklist"/>
    <span>CHECKLIST OF CONCERNS (CHILD & ADOLESCENT AND ADULT)</span><br />
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="health"/>
    <span>HEALTH INFORMATION PRIVACY FORM</span><br />
</form>

<div id="informed" class="Form">1</div>
<div id="release" class="Form">2</div>
<div id="intake" class="Form">3</div>
<div id="checklist" class="Form">4</div>
<div id="health" class="Form">5</div>
<div id="ContactFormSix" class="Form">6</div>
```

JS

```
var myForm = new Array("INFORMED CONSENT","RELEASE OF INFORMATION","INTAKE FORM");
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input').on( 'change', function () {
      //check
      var ValUe = $(this).val();
      $('.Form').hide();
      $('#' + ValUe).show();
      //Find the value of the input that was clicked
      var formVaule = $('input[value="' + ValUe + '"]');
      //Grab the value of the input that was clicked and find the next element and retreive the text
      var k = formVaule.next().text();
      //PrePend the elemnts text   
      $('#' + ValUe).prepend(k);
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.prepend()` or `.append()` try using `.html()` this will replace the targeted elements original data.

E.g.
`$('#' + ValUe).html(k);`

**Animate example**

Just an example, could be achieved in many other ways.

```
$('#' + ValUe).html(<span style="opacity:0;">k</span>);
$('#' + ValUe span).animate({opacity:1},slow);
```

Comment: How would I go about animating .html(k) in to the div?

Comment: Like with a fade animation?

Comment: $('#' + ValUe span).animate({opacity:1},slow); this code seems to have a error. I would like to animate the .html(k) with a background-color fade in and fade out effect so i guess I would like to know how to add  a animation to fade in a background color to .html(k) and end it with with a call back function to fade out the background color

Answer (score 0):

Before prepending the data you could clean the div and then preprend:

```
$('#' + ValUe).empty(k);
$('#' + ValUe).prepend(k);
```